# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException com.google.android.maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting this error in app that uses com.google.android.maps and the message is "Unfortunately the app has stopped."

> E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3338):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime(
>   3338):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 3338): Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.createMap(MapActivity.java:575)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:423)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   com.ee.map.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:170)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime( 3338):  ... 11 more

Has anybody seen such error and do you know what can causes this?
What is in com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.createMap(MapActivity.java:575)?

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace for the exception from logcat

Comment: Actually the app works fine, the only device that has such problem is Nexus 7 with 3G. On Nexus 7 (without mobile) it works fine.

Comment: it turned out it was on a rooted device and after unrooting it works fine